# Error with Unbound Expression in Bounded Column?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

In my GridView 8 Columns are Bounded from Access DataBase. (Item, Desc, UoM, Quantity, UnitPrice, Discount%, Discount, VAT). I have GriditemLookupEdit in Item(Bounded Column). If I select any Item it fill automatically remaining columns. By Default Discount% and Discount are 0. I set Unbounded Expression to both columns(Discount% & Discount). But While runtime that expression not working if change any value in Both Column.

My Unbound Expression is

```
DiscountPercentage = "([DiscountAmount] / [UnitPrice]) * 100.0"

DiscountAmount = "[UnitPrice] * ([DiscountPercentage] / 100.0)"
```

this is not working in Unbound Column. Is is any way to possible to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use Unbound Expression in the Bounded Column. Instead off using unbound expression we can use this code to calculate in CellValueChanged event

```
 var row = gridView1.GetFocusedDataRow();

if (e.Column == colDiscountAmout)
{
    var productPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]);
    var discountAmout = Convert.ToDecimal(row["DiscountAmout"]);
    row["DiscountPercent"] = (discountAmout * 100) / productPrice;
}


if (e.Column == colDiscountPercent)
{
    var productPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]);
    var discountPercent = Convert.ToDecimal(row["DiscountAmout"]);
    row["DiscountAmout"] = productPrice * (discountPercent / 100);
}
```